# Network locations like OSX

Tags: debian, networking

I couldn't find anything like that on Google, so I am asking it here.
Is there a way to make multiple network configurations that can be activated with one click like OSX? 
Like for example, one that keeps DHCP, the other static etc, but I don't want to manually input the parameters every time.

Using Debian

Thanks

Comment: What desktop environment do you use (Gnome, KDE, LXDE, …)?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found it while searching another thing. It's in the network configuration control panel, I only have to add another interface with the same MAC and it appears on the top bar on the right.